# how can i make this header 100% wide?

Tags: html, css, header, positioning

I want to make this header 100% wide.  I tried this on jsfiddle, but there's still some more margin left on the left and right.

CSS:

```
#header {
   background: url("../img/top-bg.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 #3D668F;
   height: 44px;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

Fiddle: http://www.jsfiddle.net/VgfaA/

jsfiddle has thier header 100% wide, so thats an good example!!! I even tried to put width:100% but it still doesn't work

Comment: Have you tried that on browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added

```
html, body { padding:0;margin:0; }
```

:) Nice site